# How to use Selenium RC for Selenium IDE test cases dependency?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, gui-testing

I have an authentication test case made in Selenium IDE that must be executed before every other test. I don't want to use them ordered inside a test suite because if I make some change in the authentication test case, it would be necessary to change every test case suite that uses it.

Is there a way to specify this **test case dependency** or **test case execution order** when running Selenium RC Server? Something like:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar <path>\authentication_test_case.html <path>\application_feature1_test_case.html <path>\report.html`

or then

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar <path>\authentication_test_case.html <path>\application_feature2_test_case.html <path>\report.html`

My need is that a change made in authentication test case doesn't influence the other test cases/suites that depend on it. Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized how to specify this test case dependency in Selenium using test suites. Just need to reference the test case without copying it's execution code:

```
<td><tr><a href="<path>\authentication_test_case.html">Step 1 - Authentication</a></td></tr>
<td><tr><a href="<path>\application_feature1_test_case.html">Step 2 - Application Feature 1</a></td></tr>
```